# compiling gcc7 and gcc on ubuntu without internet

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, deb

I am trying to get ubuntu up and running but I do not have working internet on that machine. That means no apt or updates or anything that is not included with the .iso from Ubuntu.
I have tried the apt-get --print command but it fails saying that gcc is not a valid package.
I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with a USB using Rufus and an .iso 
I tried adding main to my source.list and that did not help. 
I was able to get make working via a .deb file so I am thinking there is hope

So now I am left to trying to get gcc up and running from the .tar files from Ubuntu. The tutorials that I have found are either outdated or incorrect.  Does anyone have a good tutorial that can help me through the process of getting gcc7 and gcc working on Ubuntu without internet?
Or maybe is there a complete listing of the file dependencies for gcc7 and gcc using .deb files(not sure this is possible)?

Thanks

Comment: "I do not have working internet on that machine" - if you solve *that* issue, both your immediate problem and a lot of *future* problems will disappear in one fell swoop :-)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear... I have a Netgear wifi adapter so I can have internet but the linux driver requires make and gcc in order to run correctly, hence my post. I already installed the .deb for make I just need gcc to be built and I will hopefully be good to go, then its sudo apt-get update away!

Comment: I think it would be easier to just install what you need, rather than building it, because the build dependencies for gcc surely include a C compiler: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline